# evaluateDynamicContent() is disallowed

Tags: craft4, yii, debugging

Bug while installing debug toolbar in Craft 4 latest version:

```
An Error occurred while handling another error:
yii\base\NotSupportedException: evaluateDynamicContent() is disallowed. in /craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/View.php:1884
```

in /craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/View.php error is thrown due to 'allowEval' is not set to true?

```
@inheritdoc
@throws NotSupportedException unless [[allowEval]] has been set to `true`.

public function evaluateDynamicContent($statements)
{
    if (!$this->allowEval) {
        throw new NotSupportedException('evaluateDynamicContent() is disallowed.');
    }

    return parent::evaluateDynamicContent($statements);
}
```

Also setting `$allowEval = true;` is not recommended.

References:
https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-debug

How can I resolve this error to start using the debug toolbar?

Comment: Yii's debug toolbar is included by default in Craft. You only need to activate it in your user settings. How are you "installing" it?

Comment: The craft docs are referencing to the github link. And I have installed it with composer: composer require --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-debug
I'm new to craft, where do I have to enable this in the user settings?

Comment: Found it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

**As the debug toolbar is build-in, you do not have to add it with composer.**

You can **enable** the **build-in** debug toolbar in the **upper right corner** on your control panel.

1. Click on your user account
2. Tab: preferences
3. Scroll down to: Development
4. Check both items under 'Debug Toolbar'